# Is there an alternative to ieee_divide function in SSMS as it is not recognizing while I am using it

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

```sql
Select *, ieee_divide(SuccessfulAttempts,DepositAttempts)*100 as SuccessRate from(
SELECT ct.brandName, pm.PaymentMethodName, COUNT(t.mk_paymentstatus) AS DepositAttempts, SUM(CASE WHEN t.mk_paymentstatus = 2 then t.amount_EUR else 0) as SuccessfulAttempts
FROM dbo.[DBTest.deposits.transactions] t
JOIN dbo.[DBtest.dim.customers] ct ON t.mk_customer = ct.mk_Customer
JOIN dbo.[DBtest.dim.PaymentMethod] pm ON pm.mk_PaymentMethod = t.mk_PaymentMethod
Group by ct.brandName, pm.PaymentMethodName;
```

Error I get is

> 'ieee_divide' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Do your tables really have names like that..? I really suggest you rethink those names... They are, with respect, terrible and awfully confusing.

Comment: Is there any alternative to ieee_divide in SQL-server? I tried Google but it is not pointing out in the right direction

Comment: You'd be better off explaining what `ieee_divide` does, and then we can tell you how to do it in SQL Server.

Comment: ieee_divide is a bigquery function which is used to divide X by Y and returns the value in float64. I used to because i wanted to avoid errors for division as I have zero values too.

Comment: it seems that your current version of the SQL server engine does not recognize it, upgrade your SQL server to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use

```
 SuccessfulAttempts/nullif(DepositAttempts,0)*100
```

or

```
SuccessfulAttempts/case DepositAttempts when 0 then null else DepositAttempts end*100
```

to prevent a query from failing with

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that!

Comment: Note that this doesn't tell you if the division was +inf, -inf, or was Nan, nor does it help at all if the division itself overflowed (so not a general solution to `ieee_divide`), but presumably OP doesn't need to know that.

Comment: Yep.  I couldn't even figure out how to generate a `float` of NaN or +-inf, so went with an idiomatic translation, rather than a literal one.

Comment: Best I could suggest if you needed a +-imf would be to use a iTVF which returns 2 columns, and in the first is `NULL` the second has a non-`NULL` `varchar` value with the needed value. Not quite the same, but would at least expose the information.